# Div border not re-painting after scrolling in IE7

Tags: css, html

There is a problem only in IE7 where the border of a div is not being re-painted after scrolling.  If the is not in the window after scrolling then shown again it shows up as white.

here is an example of what I'm talking about:

http://imagebin.antiyes.com/467

I've made the `border: 10px` to make it stand out, it should always be solid.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like the peekaboo bug. Try setting "zoom: 100%" on the box class.

Comment: that fixed it! cant believe it was that easy.

Answer (score 2):

There's a few good articles out there about the peekaboo bug.  It's worth taking the time to understand the common causes if you can, as it makes it easier to avoid it in the future :)

useful info: http://www.positioniseverything.net/explorer/peekaboo.html