# IE6 screwing the pooch here... what the hey!

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-6

http://sensenich.bythepixel.com/support/faq

If you look at the link in IE6 styling appears only when you scroll down.  Then when you scroll back up it disappears.  How is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: could you try a better question title?

Comment: this may be the best question title i have ever seen...

Comment: this sounds similar to the question i had here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/533028/div-border-not-re-painting-after-scrolling-in-ie7

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you want to use IE 6.

Comment: Can you explain the issue more and provide some of the applicable code?  I'm looking at the site in IE6 and don't see much of a difference between the rendering there or in Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have IE6 anymore but judging by the source I'd say jQuery is responsible. You might be better off not trying to be so fancy in IE6 and just focus on giving them the information. It's a dying browser anyway.

```
    <!--[if lte IE 6]>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/js/supersleight-min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                    $('#logo, #midfooter').supersleight();
            });
    </script>
<![endif]-->
```

This. Do you REALLY need it? On second thoughts, maybe you do need it, but try removing it to see if it's the culprit. If it is there are other scripts that solve the transparency problem you might have more luck with.

Comment: There's still people running IE6, and I don't pretend to be all high and mighty about what browsers people use.  Not everyone's an internet guru.

Comment: There's still people running Netscape 4. I get your point but I'm not saying ignore them, i'm just saying remove the 'window dressing' and give them a plainer layout.

Comment: I just realized my response was kinda rude.  Actually the real reason for me wanting IE6 compatibility is because that's what we told our client.  I'm learning more and more that this is just a bad move.

Comment: Personally, I treat IE6 the same way I treat mobile browsers and browsers with javascript turned off: just serve them a traditional CGI web form app! Try this, turn off javascript in your web browser then go to http://maps.google.com . See? **Google maps is still usable without javascript!**. The key is to be able to **serve the data**, not the fancy ui tricks.